# Get Id of inserted data (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have code in controller that write data from View to table

Here is code

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen()
    {
        // Формируем список команд для передачи в представление
        SelectList teams = new SelectList(db.Vacancy, "VacancyId", "VacancyName");
        ViewBag.Teams = teams;
        SelectList teams2 = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
        ViewBag.Teams2 = teams2;
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen(Interview interview)
    {
        db.Interview.Add(interview);
        db.SaveChanges();
        int id = interview.Interview_Id;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions");
    }
```

Here is model

```
   [Key]
    public int Interview_Id { get; set; }
    public string Greeting { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> VacancyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Vacancy Vacancy { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Interwier> Interwiers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<InvitationMail> InvitationMails { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MassLink> MassLinks { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionBlock> QuestionBlocks { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have  `Interview_Id`

I try to make it like this, but it not works `int id = interview.Interview_Id;`

How I can write id to variable?

Comment: Post your Interview model here. Interview_id should be decorated as primary key.

Comment: I updated my post@Krishna

Comment: @EugeneSukhomlin, what you are doing seems correct to me. The 2 things that you should try is `[Key][DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InterviewId { get; set; }` & second rename Interview_Id  to InterviewId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question right. You might have something like this.

`public DbSet<Interview> Interviews {get; set;}`

Rename Interview_Id to simply Id or InterviewId (no underscore).

```
public class Interview
{
 [Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int InterviewId { get; set;}
 // other properties 
 }
```

DAL Method.

```
public int Add(Interview inteview)
{
     using(DbContext entities = new DbContext()
     {
         entities.Interviews.Add(interview);
         entities.SaveChanges();
         var id = interview.InterviewId; 

        return id;
     }

}
```

From your Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult WelcomeScreen(Interview interview)
{
   Dal dalObj = new Dal();
   var inteviewId = dal.Add(interview);
   //use this id
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to write DAL in controller?

Comment: [DAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) Ideally you should create it as separate project of type Class Library & write all your DB related stuff here & then reference it in the UI Layer & call DAL methods.

Comment: So I need to create Portable Class Library?

Comment: Also, why I need to rename property, if in database it's Intrewiev_Id

Comment: No not portable library simple class library will do.

Comment: are you getting the id??

Comment: For now, not, I try to make this via Class Library, as you said.

Comment: Since you are using EF I guess you're well aware about this.  `using(DbContext entities = new DbContext()
     { }`

Comment: In Table all writing, But I cant write id to variable with methods I doin before. Will try your solution

Comment: I do it, but I have 6 reputation

Comment: Please check this link. It add more info & sure enough this post will solve your question https://codepaste.net/uq5o9o

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult WelcomeScreen(Interview interview)
        {
            db.Interview.Add(interview);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int id = db.Interview.Max(x=>x.Interview_Id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions");
        }
```

Comment: Did you check if the data is actually being inserted into the database?

Comment: Yes, it's in database. And id is 1051 there

Comment: `[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Interview_Id { get; set; }`

 try this on your entity

Comment: try this. var result = db.Interview.OrderByDescending(x => x.Interview_id).First();

Comment: Did you check interview.Interview_Id ? Where did you out the breakpoint?

Comment: I set breakpoint here `int id = db.Interview.Max(x=>x.Interview_Id);` @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: set a watch on id look for value after the operation executed or set break point on this line`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions");`

Answer (score 0):

check you dbml
make sure you have this attribute set correctly

```
AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert
```

the full attribute usually like this

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
```